# Use lightning-formatted-date-time inside <a> tag

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, html

I want to use `<lightning-formatted-date-time>` inside `<a>` tag but it displays Page doesn't exist.

I have a requirement to display *code - name - formatted date* as a url to point to the object.

My code is as follows :

```
<dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick={handleView} title="View Detail" data-id={object.Id} class="link-style">
        {object.Code__c} - {object.Name__c}
        <template if:true={object.Effective_Date__c}>
           - <lightning-formatted-date-time
              value={object.Effective_Date__c} year="numeric"
              month="numeric" day="numeric">
           </lightning-formatted-date-time>
        </template>
    </a>
</dd>
```

When clicking on code or name the link redirects to the proper view, but on clicking on date part it says page doesn't exist, enter a valid url and try again.

Kindly help, I need to format the dynamic date to *mm/dd/yyyy* format and also it should point to the correct view on click.

Comment: Have you tried constructing formatted date string in the js instead of using <lightning-formatted-date-time>?

Comment: @NagenSahu As the date is coming from inside the object inside for loop, so can you tell me how to construct that inside js. I can do that for a normal parameter, but didnt get how to do that for a dynamic object inside for loop as the object is constructed as `{object.Effective_Date__c}`